# Trying to get ons-template id value

Tags: jquery, onsen-ui

Im having trouble for gettin currently loaded (page which is displayed at the moment) ons-template id  , etc `id="page1.html`"   or `id="page2.html"`.

Code what i am tring to use is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var t = ons.findComponent('ons-template', document.body);
});
```

im getting `null` with that

and othe sample code is

```
var template =$('ons-template').attr('id');
console.log(template,t);
```

but with that im getting `undefined`.

template example :

```
<ons-template id="page1.html">
    <ons-page>
        <p style="text-align: center; color: #999; padding-top: 100px;">Page1 Contents</p>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

i have tried different approches, but still nothing.

Comment: what are these pages going into ? tabbar ?

Comment: pages are in slaidmenu and they are going into pages which display info. Or what to you mean ?

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/djtfzLeh/2/ ?

Comment: allmost, but i want to get current page id , like when its menu.html then it will display menu.html on console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the sliding menu object by using `ons.findComponent('ons-sliding-menu')`.

The object has a property called `_currentPageUrl` so to get the URL of the current page you can use:

```
ons.findComponent('ons-sliding-menu')._currentPageUrl
```

The `<ons-template>` tag will be removed when the page is compiled and its content is put in the AngularJS `$templateCache` service. That's why you can't find the elements.